# Hot keys Shift+Ctrl+End and Shift+Ctrl+Home stopped working

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Hot key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> stopped working in any text editor such as Microsoft Word 2016, Notepad++ or Notepad.

My OS is Windows 10. It was really useful that I can select text without scrolling the whole document.

What can be done to have these hotkeys workable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started experiencing the same problem and narrowed it down to the "Opera" browser (version:63.0.3368.88, latest at the moment of writing). Closing Opera restored Shift+Ctrl+End or Shift+Ctrl+Home behavior for me.

UPDATE: I've found the related topic on Opera forums: https://forums.opera.com/topic/35038/latest-opera-update-breaks-essential-ctrl-shift-home-end-windows-shortcuts

Comment: Great, thank you so much, was driving me insane! Here's a solution https://forums.opera.com/topic/34954/opera-shortcut-key-delete-history/5 for tech savy users: Open `"%appdata%/Opera Software/profile/preferences"` with your favourite Editor, and remove the nasty `ctrl+shift+home/end` shortcuts or set them "global: false"

Answer (score 2):

Some program might have taken over these shortcuts.

Try to boot in Safe Mode and check if this is still happening,
then reboot in normal mode.

If it is still happening, then Windows is corrupted.
Try to check its integrity using
[SFC and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

If it is not happening any more, then some installed program is sabotaging these
hotkeys. Download and install
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
and run it to see all startup programs. You can here disable and enable programs
by their check-mark. If you cannot guess which one is it, you will need to do
the hard way by unchecking them in bunches and rebooting.
Re-enable those that cause no problem.

Answer (score 2):

To put [Bruno's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1483045/hot-keys-shiftctrlend-and-shiftctrlhome-stopped-working?newreg=6f8bbee457ba45e09848eb820cd95664#comment2245113_1483378) into a proper answer, this is how you fix it, taken from the Opera forums:

https://forums.opera.com/topic/34954/opera-shortcut-key-delete-history/5

Close Opera, then navigate to Opera's folder inside your appdata folder. It may look something like:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable
```

Inside that folder is a Preferences file (no file extension). Open it and delete the Control-Shift-End and Control-Shift-Home keys in the JSON. For me, in Notepad, it looks like:

[image]

Delete that, then you can use Opera again without it breaking the Windows key combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Dell Display Manager grabs ctrl + shift + Home

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000060112/what-is-dell-display-manager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1107112)